Inquiry Regarding View Limits on Google Docs and Google Apps Script
I am writing to inquire about certain view and usage limitations related to Google Docs and Google Apps Script, specifically regarding access restrictions or quotas.
In several instances, I encountered an error message such as

“Exception: Quota exceeded: Document”

when running scripts in Google Apps Script. I believe this issue may be related to restrictions on the number of views or access to documents via the Google Docs API or Google Apps Script.
I have a few questions related to this:
1.What are the access limitations (daily or per-minute quotas) applied to viewing and using Google Docs through Google Apps Script?
2.Is there a way to track remaining daily quota or monitor service usage for the day? If so, how can I access this information?
3.Are there quota differences between standard Google accounts and Google Workspace (paid) accounts for accessing Google Docs through Google Apps Script?
4.If I need to increase my view quota or API access through Google Apps Script, are there any recommended solutions?
5.What are the best practices for managing or optimizing the use of the Google Docs API through Google Apps Script to avoid quickly reaching the quota limits?
I would greatly appreciate any information you can provide on these restrictions, as well as suggestions for effectively managing quotas. Thank you for your time and assistance.
Error From Google Doc
[Error from AppsScript
Actually I want a similar feature like Google Doc which can connect to SpreadSheet with Unlimited Bandwidth

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please ask only one question per post. Post another question instead. See How do I ask a good question?

#2 already has an answer in this post

For #3 and #4, you should contact Google Workspace Support for this. They can help you decide for a good option suited for you (for #3) and when or how to upgrade (for #4).


1.What are the access limitations (daily or per-minute quotas) applied to viewing and using Google Docs through Google Apps Script?

There is no specific limit to viewing Google Docs text documents.
From the documentation:
Quotas are set at different levels for users of consumer (such as gmail.com) or G Suite free edition (discontinued) accounts and Google Workspace accounts. Quotas are per user and reset 24 hours after the first request.



Quota
Consumer (e.g., gmail.com)
Google Workspace accounts




Documents created
250 / day
1,500 / day


Files converted
2,000 / day
4,000 / day






Limits
Consumer (e.g., gmail.com)
Google Workspace accounts




Script runtime
6 min / execution
6 min / execution


Custom function runtime
30 sec / execution
30 sec / execution


Google Workspace Add-on runtime
30 sec / execution
30 sec / execution


Simultaneous executions per user
30 / user
30 / user


Simultaneous executions per script
1,000
1,000



See Quotas for Google Services.

I don't think "Additional limits apply for trial accounts...." is relevant or applicable here. Those restrictions only apply to Email sent quota(I think). Only the email quota has a * next to it, which directly links it to this section, which has a star at the start.

@TheMaster good catch.
